# Deleting Specific Record Using ObjectID

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, mongodb, cherrypy

I'm defining a delete function in which, there's a delete button in each row, sending the ObjectID of that specific record to my **Server Side**, therefore, this ObjectId will be checked with the one stored in the database, resulting in deletion of that certain record, so far I could have make a good progress sending data's over, and checking on it, but I"m suspecting the ObjectId being sent, requires some sort of casting. Currently, the code and responses are as below;

**Front-End (Index.Html)**

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item active" >
    List Of Notes
</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="r in retrieve" >
    {{r.create_at}} 
    <button style="float:right" type="button" ng-click="delete_note(r.ObjectId)" 
     class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
         Delete  <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
    </button>
</a>
```

**AngularJS (main.ctrl.js)**

```
$scope.delete_note = function (data_id) {
    $http.get('/delete_note', {
        params: data_id
    }).success(function(data){
        console.log(data)
    });
}
```

**Back-End (Root.py)**

```
@cherrypy.expose
@cherrypy.tools.json_out()
@cherrypy.tools.json_in()
def delete_note(self,*args,**kwargs):
res2=self.my_app.delete_note(kwargs)
return "<h1>delete success </h1>" +str(res2)
pass
```

**Back-End (App.py)**

```
def delete_note(self, index):
return self.db.notes.remove({'_id': index})
```

The current message appears in Google Chrome Console.log is this :

```
<h1>delete success </h1>{'ok': 1, 'n': 0}"
```

Which is obviously stating that, nothing has been changed within the database, I'm using Cherrypy, Mongodb, and Angularjs, any consideration is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you putting a button element inside an anchor element?

Comment: just to have them both in a relevant location, anchor for the "list group items" and buttons to be added in front of each record, is it possible that it may cause issues ?

Comment: Well an anchor is normally something you can click on, and which you can tab to using the keyboard, so having another clickable item like a button inside an anchor is a bit weird.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be hard to locate the exact problem, but there are a few things that call for attention:

1. As nnnnnn already pointed out, nesting a `button` in an anchor (`a`) element is odd and might lead to weird issues.
2. The directive `ng-click="delete_note(r.ObjectId)"` looks odd: Does your python code really remap the `_id` field to a field called `ObjectId`? `ObjectId` is the *type* of (default) keys in MongoDB, the convention for the *name* is `_id`.
3. To find out, take a look at the network inspector when you GET the original data (i.e., `$scope.retrieve`) - what does it send? It's also helpful for debugging to output `<pre>{{retrieve | json}}</pre>` so you can see what ends up at angular
4. You're apparently deleting using a `GET`. While there's nothing that prevents you from doing that, writing with GETs is bad practice. If you possibly can, delete using an HTTP `DELETE`. If that's completely impossible for whatever reason, at least use a POST. But a GET should be nullipotent, i.e. it shouldn't change the server state *at all*.
5. The parameter to a REST request should be part of the URL, so your delete should read

   `DELETE /notes/:noteId`, e.g. `DELETE /notes/54fadec1e4259ded64c7576a`

   Putting the identifying parameter somewhere else violates the idea of resource urls.